# Youtube get wide view

Tags: youtube, google-account

How do I get the wider view in Youtube?

Me and my friend have the same display with the same resolution. However, youtube has a wider view on my friends display while my view is narrow.

I think I have to edit some settings in Youtube/Google account.

I tried logging in into his account using my PC and seems that now I get the wider view.

My view:
[image]

The view I want
[image]

Comment: A couple of things to check: 1. Scaling (system-wide) 2. zoom feature (browser)

Comment: @MichaelBay I tried using his account on the same system and I get a wider view

Comment: Try disabling all Chrome extensions you have, and reload the page after you do this.

Comment: I think it's just the new look that at the time you haven't gotten yet. I haven't changed anything, and still working with the same display and settings - and it very recently changed for me.

Answer (score 1):

In short: **Make your viewport larger**

In long:

YouTube tries to make the player fit your screen in a way that makes the default player neither too large (which would cut off information in the description), nor too small (which would make it difficult to watch the video). Therefore, it uses the width and height of the viewport (ie the part of your browser that actually displays the website) to determine the most appropriate size.

Making YouTube think that you have the appropriate size can be done in the following ways:

- Go into full screen mode (F11)
- Hide toolbars, bookmark bars, and/or the Windows task bar.
- Use a userscript or extension that sets the player size to something more that's more of your liking. There are so many of these "YouTube enhancers" or "improvers" that I cannot recommend any particular of them, I will however put a warning here that one of the most popular ones - *Magic Actions for YouTube* - recently has caused scam popups.

Answer (score -1):

Try another browser. By the way, I was able to reproduce both views by changing zoom in the browser.

Comment: Change the zoom and the youtube logo will change size...
the photo shows equal size logo.